# PulseAudio doesn't load "module-echo-cancel" after restarting

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I had a problem with my microphone and solved it by adding `load-module module-echo-cancel` to `/etc/pulse/default.pa` and running `pulseaudio -k` after it. It solves my problem but when I restart computer it dose not load again and I have to run `pulseaudio -k` command every time I shutdown and start the computer again. What do I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

There is a man page for `default.pa`, which says:

> The  PulseAudio  sound  server  interprets  a  configuration  script on startup, which is mainly used to define the set  of  modules  to  load.
> When  PulseAudio  runs  in  the  per-user  mode and ~/.config/pulse/default.pa exists, that file is used. When PulseAudio runs  in  the  per-user  mode  and that file doesn't exist, /etc/pulse/default.pa is used.
> When PulseAudio runs as a system service, /etc/pulse/system.pa is used.

This suggest you might try duplicating your load module in `/etc/pulse/system.pa`

It seems like it might be loading as a system service when you reboot your computer, but in per-user mode when you run `pulseaudio -k`.  Therefore, if you move the line to the system-wide settings, it should available from reboot or after a `-k`.

Comment: it dose not work :((

Comment: What do you get when you run `pulseaudio --dump-conf`?

Also: In `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`, what options are set for `default-script-file=` and is `load-default-script-file=` set to yes?

Comment: ```default-script-file = /etc/pulse/default.pa``` and ```load-default-script-file = yes```

Comment: use    ~/.config/pulse/default.pa to load your module (create it if not existing)